# Fix End spawn in playerdata?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've managed to spawn *inside* the End Island, causing an immediate crash on startup.

I've attempted to modify my `dimension` and `pos` in my playerdata, but no matter what I set it to, the next time I log in I'm back at 0,9,0 and triggering the immediate crash again.

I've even tried setting spawnForce to 1.

What next?  Why is the UUID.dat file being ignored, then overwritten?

Answer (score 4):

In singleplayer worlds, the player data stored in `Player` key of the `level.dat` file itself overrides the player data stored in the `playerdata/<UUID>.dat` files. You need to edit the former file to actually change your position.

See [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_level_format#level.dat_format)